# Python math logic error

Tags: python, math

```
for i in range(1,11):
    print(i,end=":")
    if i < 100:
        square = i * i
        print(square)
```

so with the code above ill get the following output:

```
1:1
2:4
3:9
4:16
5:25
6:36
7:49
8:64
9:81
10:100
```

now I am trying to add the total of the numbers on right with this new piece of code:

```
for i in range(1,11):
    print(i,end=":")
    if i < 100:
        square = i * i
        total = square + square
        print(square)
print(total)
```

and I get the following output:

```
1:1
2:4
3:9
4:16
5:25
6:36
7:49
8:64
9:81
10:100
200
```

my math logic is clearly off but I can't seem to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you did't defined total before and you are adding twice the square instead of adding the square to total.

FROM:

```
for i in range(1,11):
    print(i,end=":")
    if i < 100:
        square = i * i
        total = square + square
        print(square)
print(total)
```

TO:

```
total = 0
for i in range(1,11):
    print(i,end=":")
    if i < 100:
        square = i * i
        total = total + square
        print(square)
print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a `total=0` before the loop and switch your

`total = square + square` to `total += square`